# How to replace some numbers with other in from one line?

Tags: python

I have line include some numbers with underscore like this

```
1_0_1_A2C_1A_2BE_DCAAFFC_0_0_0
```

I need code to check (DCAAFFC) and if the last 4 numbers not (0000) then the code should be replacing (0000) in place of last 4 numbers (AFFC) like this (DCA0000)
So should be line become like this

```
1_0_1_A2C_1A_2BE_DCA0000_0_0_0
```

I need code work on python2 and 3 please !!

P.S the code of (DCAAFFC) is not stander always changing.

Comment: the `replace()` method didn't work here?

Comment: can you give more examples, if you only give one case then we wont be able to help you generalize the code

Comment: What have you tried? SO can help you with specific problems, but is not a homework-writing service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`code=1_0_1_A2C_1A_2BE_DCAAFFC_0_0_0`
I will assume that the format is strictly like this. Then you can get the `DCAAFFC` by `code.split('_')[-4]`. Finally, you can replace the last string with 0000 by `replace`.

Here is the full code

```
>>> code="1_0_1_A2C_1A_2BE_DCAAFFC_0_0_0"
>>> frag=code.split("_")
['1', '0', '1', 'A2C', '1A', '2BE', 'DCAAFFC', '0', '0', '0']
>>> frag[-4]=frag[-4].replace(frag[-4][-4:],"0000") if frag[-4][-4:] != "0000" else frag[-4]
>>> final_code="_".join(frag)
>>> final_code
'1_0_1_A2C_1A_2BE_DCA0000_0_0_0'
```

Comment: Your code good .. But I need first code to checking value of (DCAAFFC) if last number not (0000) then replacing. The line is not standar .... some time like this (1_0_1_A2C_1A_2BE_DCAAFFC_0_0_0) some time like this (1_0_1_12A_10_15_AABFTE_0_0_0) some time like (1_0_1_AB_1B_12C_BCA1253_0_0_0) So I need only checking value number (13) like (BCA1253) or (AABFTE) or (DCAAFFC)

Comment: so you just need to check for the last 4 letters of the string in `frag[-4]` is "0000" or not and replace it with "0000". Actually, I think it is redundant, you still switch back to the format xxx0000 regardless of the cases, right?

Comment: or what you mean is you will only switch to 0 if the letter is not a number?

Comment: Thank you .. I have used your code ... very useful . no more codes need it for searching.

Comment: haha. Thank for your compliment. Have a good day on stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

Try regular expressions i.e:

```
import re

old_string = '1_0_1_A2C_1A_2BE_DCAAFFC_0_0_0'
match = re.search('_([a-zA-Z]{7})_', old_string)
span = match.span()
new_string = old_string[:span[0]+4] + '0000_' + old_string[span[1]:]
print(new_string)
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this a general string or just some hexadecimal representation of a number? For numbers in Python 3, '_' underscores are used just for adding readability and do not affect the number value in any way.

Say you have one such general string as you've given, and would like to replace ending 4 characters of every possible subgroup bounded within '_' underscores having length more than 4 by '0000', then one simple one-liner following your `hexadecimal_string` would be:

```
hexadecimal_string = "1_0_1_A2C_1A_2BE_DCAAFFC_0_0_0"
hexadecimal_string = "_".join([ substring if len(substring)<=4 else substring[:-4]+'0'*4 for substring in hexadecimal_string.split('_')])
```

Here,

- `hexadecimal_string.split('_')` separates all groups by '_' as separator,
- `substring if len(substring)<=4 else substring[:-4]+'0'*4` takes care of every such substring group having length more than 4 to have ending 4 characters replaced by '0'*4 or '0000',
- such for loop usage is a list comprehension feature of Python.
- `'_'.join()` joins the subgroups back into one main string using '_' as separator in string.

Other answers posted here work specifically well for the given string in the question, I'm sharing this answer to ensure your one-liner requirement in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

If the length of the string is always the same, and the position of the part that needs to be replaced with zero is always the same, you can just do this,

```
txt = '1_0_1_A2C_1A_2BE_DCAAFFC_0_0_0'
new = txt[0:20]+'0000'+txt[-6:]

print(new)
```

The output will be

```
'1_0_1_A2C_1A_2BE_DCA0000_0_0_0'
```

It would help if you gave us some other examples of the strings.